# Encode audio from iphone mic into gsm

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, wav, gsm

I'm using monotouch to create iphone applications and I need to encode audio that I receive from the mic into a gsm file.

I have already encoded audio into wav, but now, for more specific needs, I need to record it into GSM. If someone could tell me or show me some doc that explains either how to encode from mic into gsm or how to convert wav into gsm that would be awesome.

Ty,
Axel

**--- UPDATE ---**

There's an entry for MicrosoftGSM in `MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType`, yet I get a 1718449215 OSStatus error. I guess that the reason is that my other arguments aren't corrent. Tough I don't know the specification for saving as GSM. Here's my not working code:

```
//set up the NSObject Array of values that will be combined with the keys to make the NSDictionary
        NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
        {    
            NSNumber.FromFloat (44100.0f), //Sample Rate
            NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int)MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.MicrosoftGSM),
            NSNumber.FromInt32(2),
            NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AVAudioQuality.High),
        };
        //Set up the NSObject Array of keys that will be combined with the values to make the NSDictionary
        NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
        {
            AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
        };          
        //Set Settings with the Values and Keys to create the NSDictionary
        settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (values, keys);
```

Comment: this one is hard, you might need to find whether a c# or c/c++ way to convert wav to gsm and then port it to iOS

Comment: Ohhh yeah you are right hold on let me see if I can help you with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, there is no built in way to use AVAudioRecorder to record `GSM` audio files

The only supported audio recording formats are

- MPEG4AAC
- AppleLossless
- AppleIMA4
- iLBC
- ULaw
- LinearPCM

Anyways you could setup a webservice and use a third party converter like [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net) that can convert the audio for you.

btw if you try to use the recorder using MicrosoftGSM format you will likely to get an OSStatus error 1718449215 which is the representation of `kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError` error

Alex

Comment: Oh well, ULaw it its then. TY thoug